# Getting Error on differential equation Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, scripting

There is a Differential equation that I had to Implement on Mathematica. But I am getting this error over and over. don't know what I did wrong

[image: Q.jpg]

I tried this but does not work.

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t]*y[t]}, {2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, 
  x[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image: photo.jpg]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code to this forum instead of only picture.

Comment: You used `=` instead of `==`.  (Look at the image which has `=`, not at the posted code, which has `==` instead.) -- You're also missing `{}`: `NDSolve[{{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t]*y[t]}, {2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == 0}}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]` or have too many: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t]*y[t], 2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, x[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an initial value for `y[0]` from `2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1`. There are two variants:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t]*y[t], 2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, 
x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol1], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

or

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t]^2 + x[t]*y[t], 2*x[t]^2 + y[t]^2 == 1, 
x[0] == 0, y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]